# How is inner join different from normal multi-table selection?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, f.type, c.id 
FROM main AS m, filter AS f, city AS c 
WHERE m.id = f.id AND c.name = m.city;
```

and

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, f.type, c.id 
FROM main AS m 
INNER JOIN filter as f ON m.id = f.id 
INNER JOIN city AS c ON c.name = m.city;
```

Both should give me the same set of outputs. I ran them for a small set of values and it worked fine, but when I ran them for a very large set of values, both returned very different number of rows (the first one return ~500K rows while the second one returned ~65K rows). Is there any difference in these two queries?

[Edit]:

I am using mysql as RDBMS.

Comment: The first one returns all results, the 2nd returns the common fields, see http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/inner-join-with-multiple-tables.php

Comment: #2 is the **ANSI / ISO** standard way of doing things - it's been preferred since the SQL:1992 standard (**more than 20 years!**). You should definitely stop using the #1 style of comma-separated list of tables...

Comment: @marc_s Even when that is the right advice, that doesn't explain why he is having different result

Comment: The two queries should be returning the same result sets, and I would expect them to have the same execution plans.  The second is the preferred method of expressing `join` in SQL.

Comment: I normally use the second method (the INNER JOIN). However, I recently replaced the first query with the second one (in one of my scripts) and results just changed. @valicu2000 Please let me know how the 1st would "return all results", by means of some example (to help me understand better)?

Comment: Seems to me that the problem is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629648/mysql-selecting-from-multiple-tables-possibly-without-joins

Comment: Did you simplify / change anything in order to show us your queries? Did possibly somebody run an update behind your back? Did you check `Query1 MINUS Query2` and `Query2 MINUS Query1` for hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when query #2 is the recommended standard. Both querys should return same result.

My sugestion. Compare those join query separated

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, f.type
FROM main AS m, filter AS f
WHERE m.id = f.id;

SELECT m.id, m.name, f.type
FROM main AS m 
INNER JOIN filter as f ON m.id = f.id;
```

And then

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, c.id 
FROM main AS m, city AS c 
WHERE c.name = m.city;

SELECT m.id, m.name, f.type, c.id 
FROM main AS m 
INNER JOIN city AS c ON c.name = m.city;
```

And let us know if there is any difference. (shouldn't be any)

Comment: Yes, I tried as you said. The results were consistent with what was expected. I investigated further and found out that a back end script was updating certain columns due to which this discrepancy came. Thanks for your support. This stands fixed.